# How to keep naming conventions clear?

Tags: reactjs, naming-conventions, dry, flux, code-organization

I try to get my code organised and DRY to scale with flexibility. Do Flux, Reflux, etc. use certain naming conventions?

I try to build a file structure with atomic design patterns in React.js.

Answer (score 0):

if you use atomic design for components:

> The first letter stands for an item category: atom, molecule,
> organism. The second word is an element type. The rest is used to
> describe variations of an element.
>
> Every atom-, molecule- and organism-layer or group within your design
> mockups should be named accordingly.

and for styles I recommend use BEM :

> BEM names intentionally use double underscores and double hyphens
> instead of single to separate Block-Element-Modifier.

Comment: Well, first of all thank you for your answer. 
Do you have an exemple in react please ? it's really "hard to get" without exemple when you're a newbie. 

thx